# php convert multidimensional array to json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, string-comparison

*PHP NEWBIE*
[PHP 7.4]

I am trying to refactor some old code.

**GOAL**: The two JSON must match.

*Code snipppet 1*: Old JSON code generated from php array

*Code snippet 2*: New JSON code generated from php array

**Objective**: Both must match, I am using php unit to compare them. For simplicity, I have removed the testing code.

**PROBLEM**: Extra set of square brackets, see image below.

*I tried* Using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, which removes the square brackets, but introduces {... john: { **"0"**: { "byEmail" ... " and ... "marie": { **"1"** { "byEmail" ...

(Naming wise: I have used John and marie, but these could be promotions, offers, packages, etc. so ignore the naming please)

**SNIPPET 1 - php code**

```
$body = [
            "data" => [
                "john" => [
                    "byEmail" => [
                        "status" => true,
                        "source" => "my-server",
                    ],
                    "byPhoneCall" => [
                        "status" => true,
                        "source" => "my-server",
                    ]
                ],
                "marie" => [
                    "byEmail" => [
                        "status" => true,
                        "source" => "my-server",
                    ],
                    "byPhoneCall" => [
                        "status" => true,
                        "source" => "my-server",
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

This gets converted to this JSON object:

```
// SNIPPET 1 - running json_encode()
{
    "data": {
        "john": {
            "byEmail": {
                "source": "my-server",
                "status": true
            },
            "byPhoneCall": {
                "source": "my-server",
                "status": true
            }
        },
        "marie": {
            "byEmail": {
                "source": "my-server",
                "status": true
            },
            "byPhoneCall": {
                "source": "my-server",
                "status": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SNIPPET 2:**

I am creating this data structure dynamically now, because future requirement may have johnByPost, johnByFax, etc.:

```
//my-file-dynamic-generation.php

public function constructArray($johnByEmail=null, $johnByPhone=null, $marieByEmail=null, $marieByPhone=null) {
        $body = [ "data" => ["john" => [], "marie" => []]];

        if ($johnByEmail !== null) {
            array_push($body["data"]["john"], $this->createKeyValuePair("byEmail", $johnByEmail));
        }

        if ($johnByPhone !== null) {
            array_push($body["data"]["john"], $this->createKeyValuePair("byPhoneCall", $johnByPhone));
        }

        if ($marieByEmail !== null) {
            array_push($body["data"]["marie"], $this->createKeyValuePair("byEmail", $marieByEmail));
        }

        if ($marieByPhone !== null) {
            array_push($body["data"]["marie"], $this->createKeyValuePair("byPhoneCall", $marieByPhone));
        }
        return $body;
    }


// HELPER func


function createKeyValuePair($title=null, $status=null, $source="my-server") {
        return [
            $title => [
                "status" => $status,
                "source" => $source,
                ]
            ];
    }
```

JSON - OUTPUT

[image: Left: Snippet 1, Right: Snippet 2]

I have tried to use json_encode($data, **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**)

That resulted me to get an extra key, which I don't want (I got .... [0] => 'marie' => ... [1] => 'john'

Appreciate reading this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new array inside the function `createKeyValuePair()` (probably to add the key). You could use the function the create the content only, and create the key inside the function `constructArray()` :

```
$body["data"]["john"]["byEmail"] = $this->createKeyValuePair($johnByEmail);
```

and the function :

```
function createKeyValuePair($status = null, $source = "my-server"): array 
{
    return [
        "status" => $status,
        "source" => $source,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem. Phew. As a php expert, would you be able to comment on my refactoring style? Is there a better way than I am doing things right now?

Comment: Difficult to say with a small piece of code (see also [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - for working code). Just a tips : don't forget to add return type to function (ex here, `: array`) to enforce the data-type flow and avoid coding errors ;)